# Transform parts of an array based on grouping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame, which has a column consisting of groups of `1` and `0` values (indexed by business day). An example as an array is given below.

```
x = np.array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
              0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 
              1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
              0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
              0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

---

I am attempting to apply the some function to each group of `1`'s. In this case, cause each group of `1`'s to decay according to some exponential function. I currently defined the following to achieve this.

```
# Find where the array switches from 1 to 0 and vice versa.
# prepend was used to maintain the original array size.
change = np.abs(np.diff(x, prepend=x[0]))

# split the array into groups of `1` and `0` values.
split = np.split(x, np.flatnonzero(change))

# transform groups of 1's to np.arange
_range = [np.arange(arr.size) if arr[0] == 1 else arr for arr in split]

# concatenate the transformed arrays
new_x = np.concatenate([np.exp(-arr) if arr[-1] != 0 else arr for arr in _range])
```

---

Giving the following (using `.round(3)`)

```
array([1.   , 0.368, 0.135, 0.05 , 0.018, 0.007, 0.002, 0.001, 0.  , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.  
       , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 1.   ,
       0.368, 0.135, 0.05 , 0.018, 0.007, 0.002, 0.001, 0.   , 0.   ,0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   
       , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ,
       0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ,0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   
       , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ,
       0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   
       , 1.   , 0.368, 0.135, 0.05 , 0.018])
```

Is there a better way using either pandas or numpy to split-apply-combine a DataFrame column but "restart" some function for each separate group/window of values? As mentioned above, the data is a time series so each group of either `1` or `0` defines the start and finish of a new but similar process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go in pandas:

```
s = pd.Series(x)
_range = s.groupby([s,s.ne(1).cumsum()]).cumcount()

# or 
# _range = s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() * s



new_x = np.exp(-_range) * s
```

And `new_x.values` is the `np.array`:

```
array([1.00000000e+00, 3.67879441e-01, 1.35335283e-01, 4.97870684e-02,
       1.83156389e-02, 6.73794700e-03, 2.47875218e-03, 9.11881966e-04,
       3.35462628e-04, 1.23409804e-04, 4.53999298e-05, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 3.67879441e-01,
       1.35335283e-01, 4.97870684e-02, 1.83156389e-02, 6.73794700e-03,
       2.47875218e-03, 9.11881966e-04, 3.35462628e-04, 1.23409804e-04,
       4.53999298e-05, 1.67017008e-05, 6.14421235e-06, 2.26032941e-06,
       8.31528719e-07, 3.05902321e-07, 1.12535175e-07, 4.13993772e-08,
       1.52299797e-08, 5.60279644e-09, 2.06115362e-09, 7.58256043e-10,
       2.78946809e-10, 1.02618796e-10, 3.77513454e-11, 1.38879439e-11,
       5.10908903e-12, 1.87952882e-12, 6.91440011e-13, 2.54366565e-13,
       9.35762297e-14, 3.44247711e-14, 1.26641655e-14, 4.65888615e-15,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00,
       3.67879441e-01, 1.35335283e-01, 4.97870684e-02, 1.83156389e-02])
```

Comment: This almost work, although after the first group, the first `1` is missing from each group

Comment: What do you mean? for example, the first group has 11 non-zero values, corresponding to 11 values `1`.

Comment: This is a bit hard to explain via text. So the second and third groups start at `3.67879441e-01` instead of `1` in your example. So in my method, when a group of `1` is transformed, the first value becomes`0`. so `1,1,1,1,1,1` becomes `0,1,2,3,4,5`. Then after applying the `np.exp` it becomes `1.   , 0.368, 0.135, 0.05 , 0.018, 0.007`. In your method, this works for the first block, but doesn't in the remaining? Not sure if that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. Please see the new `_range` assignment.